# Python - Treating the string 'NA' as Null or NaN to do fillna()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, fillna

I have a dataframe:

```py
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['bar', 'NA', 'Bar'], 'bar': ['NA', 'foo', 'NA']})
```

I would like to fill the 'NA' values using the `fillna()` function.
However, `fillna()` does not detect 'NA' as Null/NaN values.

Would I have to convert all 'NA' to NaN? Or is there a way I can treat 'NA' as NaN in my dataframe?

Comment: No. You have to replace `NA` to np.nan

Comment: `mydf.replace('NA', np.nan)` ?

Comment: Really, you should fix this elsewhere. There's no reason why `'NA'` should be stored as a string instead of a null-recognized value. Are you having some function return `'NA'` in some instances? [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) will consider that a `na_value`, along with many other forms of that string, so it should get converted to `NaN` upon read if you're parsing a file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use replace function

```
mydf.replace('NA', <value_you_want>, inplace=True)
```

Or, first, replace 'NA' with NaN and the use `fillna` method

```
import numpy as np
mydf.replace('NA', np.nan, inplace=True)
mydf.fillna(<value_you_want>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert all the 'NA' to NumPy.nan values and because python detects 'None' and not 'NA'.